# Showing that $\int_{\mathbb{C}^{n}} \log|x_1x_2 \ldots x_n - 1| dVol$ is nonzero.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am stuck on this. I would like to evaluate to show this integral is nonzero for a problem I am solving. I want to compute the following integral I would like to show it is nonzero:

$$\int_{\mathbb{C}^{n}} \log|x_1x_2 \ldots x_n - 1|  dVol \neq 0$$

Comment: Are $x_1, ...$ complex variables?

Comment: Yes they are complex variables.

Comment: Why the strange notation? Why not $\log |x_1x_2\cdots x_n-1|$?

Comment: sure I will edit it!

Comment: My first guess is the integral equals $+\infty.$

Comment: @zhw. I just want to show it is nonzero

Comment: why vote to close ?

Comment: You have a singularity when $|x_1x_2...x_n|=0$

Comment: @Schach21 I am integrating over $\mathbb{C}^n$ though

Comment: @Schach21 The singularity occurs when $x_1x_2\cdots x_n=1.$

Comment: @zwh how? $\log(1)=0$, but $\log(0)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemma: $\int_{\mathbb C}\log|z-1| \,dA(z)=\infty.$ ($A$ is Lebesgue area measure on $\mathbb C.$)

Proof: Observe that if $|z|>2,$ then $|z-1|\ge |z|-1\ge 1.$ For such $z,$ we have $\log|z-1|\ge \log(|z|-1)\ge \log 1 = 0.$ Thus

$$\tag 1 \int_{|z|>2}\log|z-1| dA(z) \ge \int_{|z|>2}\log(|z|-1) dA(z).$$

As $|z|\to \infty,$ $\log(|z|-1)\to \infty.$ Thus the integral on the left of $(1)$ is $\infty.$ Since $\log|z-1|$ is locally integrable on $\mathbb C,$ the lemma is proved.

The lemma implies your integral is $\infty$ for all $n.$ Take $n=2$ for example. We are looking at

$$\tag 2 \int_{\mathbb C}\int_{\mathbb C}\log|zw-1| dA(z)\,dA(w).$$

We can assume $w\ne 0$ in the inner integral. Let $z=u/w.$ Then the inner integral equals

$$\frac{1}{|w|^2}\int_{\mathbb C}\log|u-1|\,dA(u).$$

By the lemma, this equals $\infty.$ Therefore $(2)=\infty$ as claimed.